Java Amazon SDK 2.x equivalent for the 1.x "S3Objects" utility class
I'm migrating a java project that was using the AWS SDK 1.x to list and iterate through objects lazily in S3.
S3Objects iterableS3Objects = S3Objects.withPrefix(amazonS3, myBucketName, myPrefix);

for (S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary : iterableS3Objects) {
...
}


I'm looking for similar functionality in the AWS SDK for Java 2.x. Is there similar functionality?
I see that in S3Client there's a "listObjectsV2" method, and that I can specify a prefix there, is that what I'm looking for? Is there a built in way to lazily get the next batch using that, or will I need to build that functionality myself?

After asking a followup-comment on another question I was led this answer that included what I was looking for.
You use the ListObjectsV2Paginator method, which does let you lazily iterate through the objects in the s3 bucket.
ListObjectsV2Iterable iterable = s3Client.listObjectsV2Paginator(request);

for (ListObjectsV2Response page : iterable) {
    for (S3Object s3Object : s3ObjectBatch.contents()) {
    ...
    };
}

